# Convex conjugate of functions that are both submodular and supermodular (for instance those with diagonal hessian) are submodular and supermodular

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Theorem 8.1 of the [discrete convex analysis book](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718508) states that

> For a submodular function $f$, the Legendre–Fenchel transform $f^•$ is supermodular.

where the Legendre-Fenchel transform (convex conjugate) is defined as
$$f^•(p) = \sup_x p^\top x - f(x).$$

Later the book states that the inverse is not true in general i.e., the convex conjugate of a supermodular function is not submodular. However proposition 8.2 states that for functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the inverse is true.

Now my question is that if the function is both submodular and supermodular (if twice differentiable, has diagonal hessian), will the convex conjugate be both supermodular and submodular?

For context the book define a function $f$ as submodular if
$$f(x)+f(y)\geq f(x\wedge y) + f(x\vee y)$$
is true for all $x$ and $y$. Note that $x\wedge y$ and $x \vee y$ are the respective element wise max and min.

Supermodular functions are the inverse i.e. $$f(x)+f(y)\leq f(x\wedge y) + f(x\vee y).$$

Submodularity in twice differentiable functions is equivalent to off diagonal nonpositity in the hessian (Proposition 2.6, hence why functions that have diagonal hessians are both submodular and supermodular)